# Need help in understanding the purpose of verbose in SimpleImputer class

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The `Scikit-learn` has replaced `Imputer` with `SimpleImputer` Class, which comes with new parameter "verbose" and it can be set to 0 or 1.

```
SimpleImputer(missing_values=nan, strategy='mean', fill_value=None, verbose=0,
    copy=True, add_indicator=False)
```

Could you please help me in understanding its purpose?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f69242646d239d89a5713982946b8ffcf9d9/sklearn/impute/_base.py#L402.). The verbose variable only used once (if it equals `1` or `True`) to warn the user when the `imputer` is trying to delete the invalid columns.